# Angular enter repeat animations inside views

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

Can it be right, that angular ng-repeat animations, do not trigger inside views?

I've extended some examples from this article: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

When the view change, the repeat animation is not fired. I'm expecting the repeat ng-enter to fire when the view loads — it's the 1-10 list, which should animate in from the left.
http://plnkr.co/edit/8e9RqoaKnJZf5QovoBrU?p=preview

But in this example (just copy/pasted to the view on the above link) it does:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HytaDZ0nXbGLmks9eLUx?p=preview

Comment: Could you specify what behavior you're expecting to see in your Plunk? Both plunks appear to be animating in the same way.

Comment: Allright Sarah, i've improved the question.. "I'm expecting the repeat ng-enter to fire when the view loads — it's the 1-10 list, which should animate in from the left."